# Prove that $HK\approx H \times K$ iff $H,K \triangleleft G$ and $|H \cap K|=1$

Tags: group-theory, direct-product

I am trying to prove that

$HK\approx H \times K$ iff $H,K \triangleleft G$ and $|H \cap K|=1$.

So the backwards direction is standard. However, the forward direction is giving me trouble. We are not given an epxlicit isomorphism between $HK$ and $H \times K$ which makes the matters more complicated.

What I have done so far:

$|HK|=\frac{|H||K|}{|H\cap K|}=|H||K|$ and so $|H\cap K|=1$ Now also we know either $H$ or $K$ is normal as otherwise $HK$ would not be a group. Now also note that $H,K$'s isomorphic copies  are normal in $H \times K$ but this does not seem very helpful unless we know what the isomorphism is. If the isomorphism was the natural one, namely: $hk\to(h,k)$ then we would be done as preimage of a normal subgroup is normal. Thus $H,K$ would be normal in $G$.

Any hints would be appreciated!

Comment: There are examples where $HK$ is a group and neither $K$ nor $H$ are normal in $G$. For instance, consider $G = D_8$ and let $H = \langle r ^2s\rangle$ and $K = \langle s \rangle$ where $r$ is the rotation and $s$ the reflection. One may check that $HK$ is a group but neither $H$ nor $K$ are normal in $G$.

Comment: When considering the forward direction, what is $G$?

Comment: $H,K$ are subgroups of $G$ @JuanDiegoRojas good point, noted

Comment: @Sorfosh Observe that in my example, $HK$ is isomorphic to $H \times K$ non-canonically, as both are groups of order 4 non-cyclic. In your statement, the map that $HK \cong H \times K$ must be the multiplication map.

Comment: @JuanDiegoRojas As in the map $hk\to (h,k)$ ? Then my proof works right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The forward direction is not true. For example, let $X$ be a nonabelian group and let  $G=X\times X$.

Let $H=\{(x,x)\in G\mid x\in X\}$ be the diagonal subgroup of $G$, and let $K=\{(x,1)\in G\mid x\in X\}$.

Note that  $G=HK$ and $K\cong X\cong H$ so $HK\cong H\times K$, but $H$ is not normal in $G$ (this is where we use the hypothesis that $X$ is nonabelian).